# How can I restore wine's *.desktop files?

Tags: wine

When I installed various Windows programs via wine, it generated files at `~/.local/share/applications/*.desktop`. However, these were recently mangled, so I deleted them. How can I regenerate them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To regenerate them you'd need to re-install the applications... (I suppose it's not particularly helpful if I say you can restore from backups.)

Comment: …and I've used my daily limit of votes in order to get a badge. :/ Thanks anyway!